# How we can set default route in NUXTJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

How we can customize `NUXT` routing. Currently, I am working with the default `NUXT` page routing mechanism. I want to point `example.vue` as the default landing page instead of `index.vue`. I also need to add authentication on these routing. unfortunately, `NUXT` document didn't help me well.

Answer (score 6):

Check to [middleware Property on Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware)

You can write a middleware and call it in your index.vue as:

```
middleware: {
  'redirect-to-example'
}
```

middleware/redirect-to-example.js

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  if (!store.state.authenticated) {
    return redirect(301, '/example');
  }
}
```

You find useful informations about  [The Context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context) to play well with Nuxt

Comment: thank you, How can I set the default landing page

Answer (score -1):

To change the landing page you can use the following `pages/index.vue`:

```
<template>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  created() {
    this.$router.push('/example')
  },
}
</script>
```

when the user navigates to `https://localhost:3000` the route `/projects` will be pushed and the url will change to `https://localhost:3000/example`, this can be seen as an internal "redirect".

Comment: While it works, the index page will still load and display (briefly) before it is moved. This is what I tried first and the current index page loads before moving on to the pushed route.